# How to correctly connect my front audio panel?

Tags: audio, connection, pin, front-panel

My motherboard is a gigabyte ga-a320m-h. I don't know how to plug the wires in right sequence. I tried to find the answer in the user manual, but I still don't understand how correctly connect.

Please help me with my issue.

Here is screenshot of manual and connectors. [Audio connection pinout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHX66.jpg)

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: What model case are you installing the motherboard into? You might need the case manufacturer to understand where these pins should attach. This is an excerpt from your mobo manual: "Some chassis provide a front panel audio module that has separated connectors on each wire instead of a single plug. For information about connecting the front panel audio module that has different wire assignments, please contact the chassis manufacturer."

Comment: Thank you for reply!Yes i read this note but unfortunately i could't find find a manual  of my chassis.Because i bought it a long time ago.I even don't know exact model the only thing i know the name of firm write on front"SuperPower"
I am afraid my chassis so old for my motherboard.

Comment: I can't find anything on SuperPower cases either, other than a Tom's Hardware article from 2003. You might be stuck with some trial and error, but it is tough to say with certainty that hooking up incorrectly won't cause some type of failure with the motherboard. That said, my best guess is: MIC IN > PIN 1, GND > PIN 2, MIC BIAS > PIN 3, SPKOUT R > PIN 5 + 6 > SPKOUT L > PIN 9 + 10. Nothing in pins 4, 7. Good luck. Liability is on you if you try this pinout.

Comment: Anyway thank alot for your try i appreciate that. Early i already try arbitrary connect wires,but when you said that it can cause a problem for motherboard i become a little afraid proceed my experiments.

Comment: Reversing the polarity of speakers and microphones should just affect the quality of audio you can get, but for liability sake, I wanted to be careful about the recommendation.

Comment: I try connect according as you recommended  but it isn't work(( maybe i mess with plus and minus in SPKOUT-L\R.

Comment: Sorry that pinout didn't work. Not necessarily a solution for your existing connectors, but they do sell 3rd party front panels, with the proper connectors, if you didn't mind using something else to solve the problem. There are a lot of varieties of Front Panel Expansion Bay will fit into an empty slot in the case, with USB ports and Audio Ports, like this: https://www.amazon.com/Ports-Audio-Front-Panel-Floppy/dp/B07WXP7Y8Z